# Do Daniel Handler's novels for adults share themes or tone with his Lemony Snicket work?

Tags: theme, pseudonym, lemony-snicket

Daniel Handler's *A Series of Unfortunate Events*, written under his Lemony Snicket pseudonym, delves into a great many intriguing themes -- the blindness and dysfunctionality of modern society; living with uncertainty and incomplete information; the ambiguity of moral judgments; society's tendency to clash and schism. These themes are constant and developed throughout the series.

In addition, there is a very distinct tone that Handler maintains in all his Snicket work -- quirkiness, idiosyncrasy, and dark, deadpan humor.

Do Handler's works, aimed for adults, have similar themes and/or tone? Or are they extremely different in nature?

Comment: For reference, his four books not written under the Snicket pseudonym are *The Basic Eight*, *Watch Your Mouth*, *Adverbs*, and *We Are Pirates*.

Comment: I've read (and highly recommend) *The Basic Eight.* It doesn't have (as much of) the fantasy elements present in the Lemony Snicket works, but many of the idiosyncracies and themes you like are present.

Comment: @alphabet If you're willing to flesh that out a bit (which idiosyncrasies and themes are shared?), it sounds like it would make a good answer!